# Is the triangle inequality preserved when taking the minimum of both sides?

Tags: normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

Consider the statement

$$\min\|a+b\|\leq \min\|a\|+\min\|b\|$$

where the minimum is taken over some set $C$ for which $a,b\in C$. Is this statement true? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Right hand side of your inequality is always the double of the smallest of $a, b$ and $c.$ This observation can gives you a fairly simple counter example.

Comment: @Bumblebee Nice observation. In fact you can easily see that with only two elements: if $a<b\in \mathbb N$, then $a+b>a+a$